# Show all unique values using Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Is it possible to use Pivot Table in order to return all distinct/Unique Values?

I know that it is possible to count all unqiue values but I want to return/show all unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just drag the field you need the unique data from to the row area of the PT.