# Pivot Table and Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have the following Pivot Table:

```
Product:        Type:     CalculateFeild:

TV               Small
Computer         Big
HeadPhones       Medium
```

In the Calculate feild, I want it to calculate the number of TV's that are small for the raw date which the pivot table is created from based on the two parameters/look up values: TV and Small.

I tried creating a calculated field using IF and sum but it's not working.

Is that possible? Any tips on how?

Comment: Have you tried searching on here for questions involving pivot tables? You are doing well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516446/show-all-unique-values-using-pivot-table , But how about this question & answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876238/simple-pivot-table-to-count-unique-values?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to summarize the data, not calculate it. You already put in your parameters, TV and Small. You just need to add another column that would be the summary. For example, if your raw data is like this:

```
Order number    Product     Type
101             TV          Small
102             TV          Big
103             TV          Big
104             Computer    Medium
105             TV          Small
106             TV          Small
```

Then you can use the Order number field as your summary field, and change the setting to Count. Your resulting PivotTable would be:

```
Product     Type    Count of Order number
TV          Small   3
TV          Big     2
Computer    Medium  1
```